# Advantages of using issue tracking with Source Control

Tags: git, jira

This is not really a problem I am facing but I was trying to understand what could be the possible benefits of merging issue tracking software like JIRA with source control like GIT? I tried searching online but did not find any information regarding how the integration of the two could help the developers. One benefit in my opinion could be better code review process. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

JIRA is a issue tracker and using GIT with it helps you to keep track of the various issues: stories, bugs, hotfixes etc. Overall, It's more of a benefit towards software project management than directly for the developers themselves.

Although developers could benefit from having a issue tracker which would enable them to work on a piece of work for which all the documents (requirement document, usecase document, TD etc) will be available in JIRA against the JIRA id (ID given to the "piece of work" that you're working on)

Other than that it helps to track the progress of your story (but this part and the rest you'd probably already have known)

Hope you got the answer you were looking for.